# How can I set my app's own vibration/sound settings?

Tags: android

I searched everywhere on the Web, but I couldn't find it. The AudioManager found on the web was to change the settings of the device. What I want to do is to turn off sound/vibration settings in the app even if the device is set to sound mode, and notification occurs without sound/vibration. Please help the programming masters.

I tried changing the sound/vibration settings using the setRingerMode in AudioManager, but it didn't work properly.

```html
<!-- HTML generated using hilite.me --><div style="background: #ffffff; overflow:auto;width:auto;border:solid gray;border-width:.1em .1em .1em .8em;padding:.2em .6em;"><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%">checkBox_sound<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">setOnClickListener</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">new</span> CheckBox<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">OnClickListener</span><span style="color: #333333">()</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>
            <span style="color: #555555; font-weight: bold">@Override</span>
            <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">public</span> <span style="color: #333399; font-weight: bold">void</span> <span style="color: #0066BB; font-weight: bold">onClick</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span>View v<span style="color: #333333">)</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>
                <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">if</span> <span style="color: #333333">(((</span>CheckBox<span style="color: #333333">)</span>v<span style="color: #333333">).</span><span style="color: #0000CC">isChecked</span><span style="color: #333333">())</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>
                    audioManager<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">setRingerMode</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span>AudioManager<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">RINGER_MODE_NORMAL</span><span style="color: #333333">);</span>
                <span style="color: #333333">}</span> <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">else</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>
                    audioManager<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">setRingerMode</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span>AudioManager<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">RINGER_MODE_SILENT</span><span style="color: #333333">);</span>
                <span style="color: #333333">}</span>
            <span style="color: #333333">}</span>
        <span style="color: #333333">});</span>
        checkBox_vibe<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">setOnClickListener</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span><span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">new</span> CheckBox<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">OnClickListener</span><span style="color: #333333">()</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>
            <span style="color: #555555; font-weight: bold">@Override</span>
            <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">public</span> <span style="color: #333399; font-weight: bold">void</span> <span style="color: #0066BB; font-weight: bold">onClick</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span>View v<span style="color: #333333">)</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>
                <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">if</span> <span style="color: #333333">(((</span>CheckBox<span style="color: #333333">)</span>v<span style="color: #333333">).</span><span style="color: #0000CC">isChecked</span><span style="color: #333333">())</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>
                    audioManager<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">setRingerMode</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span>AudioManager<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE</span><span style="color: #333333">);</span>
                <span style="color: #333333">}</span> <span style="color: #008800; font-weight: bold">else</span> <span style="color: #333333">{</span>
                    audioManager<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">setRingerMode</span><span style="color: #333333">(</span>AudioManager<span style="color: #333333">.</span><span style="color: #0000CC">RINGER_MODE_SILENT</span><span style="color: #333333">);</span>
                <span style="color: #333333">}</span>
            <span style="color: #333333">}</span>
        <span style="color: #333333">});</span>
</pre></div>
```

The vibration and sound settings of the device have changed from my intention. In addition, even if the app's settings are silent after setting the device to sound state, the sound and vibration occurred when the notification occurred.

It's my first time to ask questions, so you might feel uncomfortable when you look at the form. Please excuse me.

Comment: If you don't want sounds, just don't make sounds.  I don't know why you need to change the setting to stop your own app from making a sound.

Comment: As far as I know, changing the notification settings with the same channel does not change from the initial state. Shouldn't we make a total of four channels? The way to do that seems to be inefficient.